# How to create XML from a string (not a file) in Applescript?

Tags: xml, applescript

I have an Applescript that receive an XML string formatted as parameter, and I would like to read/parse data. Received string looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <win>
  <name>Documents</name>
  <target>SSD:Documents:</target>
  <listview>1</listview>
  <sidebar>0</sidebar>
  <bounds>1200, 630, 1825, 1080</bounds>
</win>
```

I saw examples with XML files but I can't figure how to populate a record based upon received string. Final record could be like this:

```
set myRecord to {name:_XML_element_name_, tg:_XML_element_target_, listview: ...}
```

Or I could use at least some variables:

```
set theName to _XML_element_name_
set theTarget to _XML_element_target_
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a new `XML data` instance from the plain text

```
set xmlText to "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
  <win>
  <name>Documents</name>
  <target>SSD:Documents:</target>
  <listview>1</listview>
  <sidebar>0</sidebar>
  <bounds>1200, 630, 1825, 1080</bounds>
</win>"

tell application "System Events"
    set xmlData to make new XML data with properties {text:xmlText}
    tell XML element "win" of xmlData
        set theName to value of XML element "name"
        set theTarget to value of XML element "target"
    end tell
end tell
```