# Use AppleScript To Parse XML Via A URL

Tags: xml, parsing, applescript

I am trying to parse data from a networked media player.

I can access the data on the player via the following endpoint:

```
http://192.168.10.2:8008/GetUserVars
```

This returns the following data:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrightSignUserVariables>
  <BrightSignVar name="CurrentLetter">W</BrightSignVar>
  <BrightSignVar name="CurrentUserName">&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W</BrightSignVar>
</BrightSignUserVariables>
```

From this I need to use AppleScript to get the values from the `BrightSignVar` XML element node whose `name` attribute is `CurrentLetter` and `CurrentUserName`.

Essentially, I want to obtain these two text nodes:

- `W`
- `&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W&amp;Q&amp;W`

I tried the following example but got errors, any ideas?

```
set theXMLFile to ((http://192.168.10.2:8008/GetUserVars) as string)

tell application "System Events"

    set CurrUser to (value of XML element "CurrentUserName")

    set CurrLetter to (value of XML element "CurrentLetter")

end tell
```

---

**Edit:**

I have also tried the following:

```
set theXMLFile to (do shell script (("curl -X GET 'http://192.168.10.5:8008/GetUserVars'")))

tell application "System Events"

    set CurrUser to XML elements of XML element "BrightSignVar" of XML element "BrightSignUserVariables" of theXMLFile whose name is "CurrentUserName"

end tell
```

This returns the response as above however I get an error when trying to set `CurrUser` as variable:

> `can't make "BrightSignUserVariables" into type integer (-1700)`

Comment: 1. Your System Events code is missing a `tell XML data of XML file theFilePath … end tell` block. 2. System Events only works on local files so use `curl` (via Standard Additions’ `do shell script` command) to download the XML data to file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.  Here's your last script with a few appropriate amendments that I believe should work:

```
set userVars to do shell script "curl -X GET 'http://192.168.10.5:8008/GetUserVars'"

tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
    tell (make new XML data with data userVars)
        tell XML element "BrightSignUserVariables"
            tell every XML element whose name="BrightSignVar" to ¬
                set {letter, username} to its value
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

When I ran it using the XML response text you provided, the return value was:

```
{"W", "&Q&W&Q&W&Q&W&Q&W"}
```

Comment: This was the part I missed `tell (make new XML data with data userVars)` when I first looked at answering this question. Nice! +1

Comment: Ditto what @user3439894 said. TIL, so thanks for sharing this CJK. I'd missed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146576/how-to-create-xml-from-a-string-not-a-file-in-applescript/56147839#56147839) previously which shows a slight variant of it.